# Upload image and retrieving in server WORDPRESS

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, image, upload

I'm trying to do uploading of image in the server and retrieving. 
 I have done something but the problem is that the image is not uploading. My script will only get the file name and then the image will be save on the server folder. This script only saves the other data but not the image, I'm not sure where is the mistake, but the path I've used is corret, also I need to retrieve the image and post it on front end.

```
 <div class="wrap">
              <form method="POST">
                    Date: <input type="text" name="class_date"> <br>
                    Event: <input type="text" name="class_name"><br>
                    <input type="hidden" value="class_sched" name="posttitle"><br>

                    <input type="hidden" name="size" value="350000">
                    Image:<input type="file" name="class_image"><br> 
                    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
              </form>  

        </div>      

    <?php

    global $wpdb;

        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {

            $target = plugins_url("/images",__FILE__);
            $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['class_image']['name']);

            $class_date = $_POST['class_date'];
            $class_name = $_POST['class_name'];
            $class_image = ($_FILES['class_image']['name']);

            $wpdb->insert('wp_calendar', array('class_name'=> $class_name, 'class_date'=>$class_date, 'class_image'=>$class_image));

             //Writes the photo to the server
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['class_image']['tmp_name'], $target))
            {

                //Tells you if its all ok
                echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['class_image']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
            }
            else 
            {

                //Gives and error if its not
                echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
            }       

        }
```

Comment: Are you sure the folder where you are trying to write the image to has 777 writing rights? (in the ftp. You can check this with programs like filezilla)

Comment: basically,. it is working,. but the image uploaded was not in the directory,.

Answer (score 0):

Add  move_uploaded_file function. In your above code only check move_uploaded_file is true or not. Because it is if statement.

Add following code after  $wpdb->insert('wp_calendar', ....

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['class_image']['tmp_name'];

move_uploaded_file function will move file from temporary folder to plugin/images folder.